# Using Storm with Redis as data source

Tags: redis, apache-storm, jedis

I have a Storm topology that needs to stream its data from a Redis instance,  I tried to run the topology reading from a single Redis instance  but nothing seems be read from Redis and when I check the returned queue it is empty. I'm using Storm version 0.9.3.

This is my `RedisQueueSpout` which is a Storm spout which will plug your topology into Redis using a specified pattern (aka key), at which it will look for input data every time Storm polls it. The spout emits a single field with the ID message to whichever bolt follows it.

```java
package storm.starter.spout;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;


public class RedisQueueSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
  static final long            serialVersionUID = 737015318988609460L;
  private SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
  private final String         host;
  private final int            port;
  private final String         pattern;
  private transient JedisQueue jq;

  public RedisQueueSpout(String host, int port, String pattern) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.pattern = pattern;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
    _collector = collector;
    Jedis newJedis = new Jedis(host, port);
    newJedis.connect();
    this.jq = new JedisQueue(newJedis, pattern);
  }

  public void close() {}

  public void nextTuple() {
    List<String> ret = this.jq.dequeue();
    if (ret == null) {
      Utils.sleep(5L);
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(ret);
      _collector.emit(new Values(ret));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void ack(Object msgId) {}

  @Override
  public void fail(Object msgId) {}

  public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("name"));
  }
}
```

This is my `JedisQueue` which is an implementation of a standard queue data structure backed by Redis. Note that the dequeue method somewhat unconventionally returns a `List<String>` as this is what the underlying Jedis implementation returns: this is due to the ability of Redis to store many values for a single key.

```java
package storm.starter;

import java.util.List;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException;

public class JedisQueue {
  private transient Jedis jedis;
  private final String pattern;

  public JedisQueue(Jedis jedis, String pattern) {
    this.jedis = jedis;
    this.pattern = pattern;
  }

  public void clear() {
    this.jedis.del(this.pattern);
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() { 
    return (this.size() == 0);
  }

  public int size() {
    return new Integer(this.jedis.llen(this.pattern).toString());
  }

  public List<String> toArray() {
    return this.jedis.lrange(this.pattern, 0, -1);
  }

  public void enqueue(String... elems) {
    this.jedis.rpush(this.pattern, elems);
  }

  public List<String> dequeue() {
    List<String> out = null;
    try {
      out = this.jedis.blpop(0, this.pattern);
    }
    catch (JedisDataException e) {
      // It wasn't a list of strings
    }

    return out;
  }
}
```

the code is taken from [Storm-jedis](https://github.com/themasterchef/storm-jedis) and for more information you can check the link.

And this is my topology:

```java
package storm.starter;

import org.tomdz.storm.esper.EsperBolt;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import storm.starter.spout.RedisQueueSpout;;

public class NameCountTopology {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String host = "10.0.0.251";
    int port = 6379;
    String pattern = "Name:*";
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    EsperBolt bolt = new EsperBolt.Builder().inputs().aliasComponent("spout").toEventType("names").outputs()
            .onDefaultStream().emit("nps").statements()
            .add("select count(*) as nps from names.win:time_batch(1 sec)").build();

    builder.setSpout("spout", new RedisQueueSpout(host,port,pattern),1);
    builder.setBolt("count-bolt", bolt, 1).fieldsGrouping("spout", new Fields("name"));


    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);


    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        conf.setNumWorkers(1);

        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());

    } else {

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("name-count-topology", conf, builder.createTopology());
        Utils.sleep(300000);
        cluster.killTopology("name-count-topology");
        cluster.shutdown();

    }
}
```

}

My Redis Key-Values are stored using HMSET in the following format :

```
HMSET Name:1 NAME Mary YEAR 1880 GENDER F COUNT 7065
HMSET Name:2 NAME Anna YEAR 1880 GENDER F COUNT 2604
...
```

This is the log from my supervisor node:

```
2016-05-04 07:37:56 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Opened spout spout:(3) 
2016-05-04 07:37:56 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Activating spout spout:(3)
2016-05-04 07:37:56 STDIO [INFO] Queue is empty... 
2016-05-04 07:37:56 c.e.e.c.EPServiceProviderImpl [INFO] Initializing engine URI 'org.tomdz.storm.esper.EsperBolt@44d83ea0' version 4.3.0 
2016-05-04 07:37:58 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Prepared bolt count-bolt:(2)
2016-05-04 07:38:54 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __metrics_tick, id: {}, [60] 
2016-05-04 07:38:54 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: __system __metrics [#<TaskInfo backtype.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$TaskInfo@70f9b3ee> [#<DataPoint [__ack-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [memory/heap = {unusedBytes=9418640, usedBytes=14710896, maxBytes=259522560, initBytes=8035520, virtualFreeBytes=244811664, committedBytes=24129536}]> #<DataPoint [__receive = {write_pos=1, read_pos=0, capacity=1024, population=1}]> #<DataPoint [__fail-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [__execute-latency = {}]> #<DataPoint [newWorkerEvent = 1]> #<DataPoint [__emit-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [__execute-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [__sendqueue = {write_pos=-1, read_pos=-1, capacity=1024, population=0}]> #<DataPoint [memory/nonHeap = {unusedBytes=1218808, usedBytes=36529928, maxBytes=224395264, initBytes=24313856, virtualFreeBytes=187865336, committedBytes=37748736}]> #<DataPoint [uptimeSecs = 77.358]> #<DataPoint [__transfer = {write_pos=0, read_pos=0, capacity=1024, population=0}]> #<DataPoint [startTimeSecs = 1.462347457159E9]> #<DataPoint [__process-latency = {}]> #<DataPoint [__transfer-count = {}]>]] 
2016-05-04 07:38:54 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message source: __system:-1, stream: __metrics_tick, id: {}, [60] 
2016-05-04 07:38:54 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: __acker __metrics [#<TaskInfo backtype.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$TaskInfo@19940834> [#<DataPoint [__ack-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [__sendqueue = {write_pos=-1, read_pos=-1, capacity=1024, population=0}]> #<DataPoint [__receive = {write_pos=1, read_pos=0, capacity=1024, population=1}]> #<DataPoint [__process-latency = {}]> #<DataPoint [__transfer-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [__execute-latency = {}]> #<DataPoint [__fail-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [__emit-count = {}]> #<DataPoint [__execute-count = {}]>]]
```

and the log keeps repeating like that.
and this is my UI after running the topology:
[storm UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9h6B.png)

Now my question is why the spout is not working and nothing is emitted, seems like nothing is picked up from Redis.

PS: I have checked the host and port and I can get data from Redis so there's nothing wrong with the connection to Redis I suppose.

Comment: Did you double check that `this.jedis.blpop(0, this.pattern);` from `JedisQueue` returns anything? Side remark: is `Spout.next()` there is no need to sleep: `Utils.sleep(5L);` -- if no output is given to the collector, Storm will "sleep" automatically to avoid busy wait.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thank you sir, the problem was exactly the `this.jedis.blpop(0, this.pattern);` from `JedisQueue`. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HMSET is for hash, and BLPOP is for list. They're not compatible.
2. BLPOP doesn't expect a pattern. It expects exact key name. Please refer http://redis.io/commands/blpop for details.
3. Since Spout executes nextTuple(), ack(), fail() methods from single thread so BLPOP with long (or infinite) timeout also blocks Spout unless one message is available to pop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you VERY much sir, you are a life savor... Since I'm a newbie I actually didn't see that...

Comment: What if I want to get all the keys matching pattern `Name:*` so that my spout can emit them,  what should I do then? seems like Hash also does not support patterns...

Comment: You can scan to get all the keys matching pattern, but it needs to scan whole key spaces in Redis, which would make latency for Spout. IMO, if you really want to consume Redis data from Spout, the best shot is using a list as queue. If you really need to store data as hash which user is stored as different key, you can store your user data twice, which one is for actual user data, other one is for queueing (only key name, or serialized full data). You can use LUA script to store data to two places atomically.